# Convert numbers [n] 0-9 to keyboard Shift+[n] characters

Tags: c#

Is there a simpler way to convert numbers to their keyboard Shift+[n] equivalent in C# other than using a case statement? Assume the use of a standard English language keyboard.

```
9=(
8=*
7=&
6=^
5=%
4=$
3=#
2=@
1=!
0=)
```

I'm not aware of a method built into the language.

Comment: Although its not the solution you seek, making a dictionary is a way without a case statement. With numbers as input, you can even make a lookup table.

Comment: Good point, that would be preferable. Make that an answer and I'll accept it unless someone can point me to a language function.

Comment: Does your solution have to be locale aware?  Different keyboards have different characters over the numbers.  That could throw a wrench in.

Comment: Another good point. No, just 0-9 equivalent on a standard English language keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggeted in the comments, you could make a lookup table, rather than using a `switch` statement.  With the [initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), the amount of coding is minimized.

```
Dictionary<int, char> shiftLookup = new Dictionary<int, char>
{
    {9, '('},
    {8, '*'},
    {7, '&'},
    {6, '^'},
    {5, '%'},
    {4, '$'},
    {3, '#'},
    {2, '@'},
    {1, '!'},
    {0, ')'}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing commas.  I put that together without compiling it and didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) where TKey will be a number (0-9) while value will be a simbol.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
char[] map = new char[] { '!', '@', ... };
```

to get one: `map[c - '0']` and don't forget to check input range.

Comment: Your approach is much simpler as long as the user doesn't branch out into shifting any other keys.  I like it.

Comment: @JonSenchyna I just think that having a `Dictionary` is an overkill. But yes, more flexible solution.

Comment: Although I initially accepted the Dictionary solution, I ended up using this in the end. Thanks @Andrey for the suggestion.